# How To Get XPerfViewer To Use Symbols

Tags: c#, .net, performance, silverlight-4.0

I am using the HeapMonitor.cmd script to pull in native memory profiling information in the attempt to diagnose a silverlight memory leak. This is using the XPerf tools.

When I use XPerfViewer the symbols are not loaded, and thus I get no stack traces.

I have added these two environment variables,

_NT_SYMBOL_PATH = SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
_NT_SYMCACHE_PATH = c:\symbols

When I start the silverlight solution in visual studio the symbols are loaded. But when I try to open XPerfViewer, no symbols are loaded.

So what am I doing wrong? should the XPerfViewer program be loading the symbols itself, or do we need VS to load them for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trick for new players! The stack column was not selected in the XPerfViewer. This means it doesn't trigger loading the symbols. It works after the stack column is selected to display. Don't assume that the stack column is selected by default!